# Force type in abstract property from abstract class

Tags: python, class, abstract-class

The following code illustrates one way to create an abstract property within an abstract base class (`A` here) in Python:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    my_abstract_property = my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    print(b.my_abstract_property)
```

One thing to note here is that the class attribute `my_abstract_property` declared in `B` could be any Python object. I can as validly set it to the above list, or a string, or an integer, or a dictionary, etc.

So my question is: how can I force the type of the abstract property in `A` such that the class attribute in `B` has to be of that type? Taking the above example: is there a way I can force it to be a list?

Comment: you'd have to write code that does that.

Comment: If you `print(repr(A.my_abstract_property))` and then `print(repr(B.my_abstract_property))` you will see that in `B` the `my_abstract_property` isn't a property anymore but an ordinary class attribute containing a list. Therefore it can't execute code when something is assigned to it.

Comment: Do you expect any `A`'s child class to have `my_abstract_property` as `property` with default `[]` (list) on access operation ?

Comment: You can't "force" anything in Python.  Even the type hints are not enforced at runtime.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, this is the intended behaviour I am looking for. Maybe this would have been clearer in the first place if I had explicitely named `my_abstract_property` as `my_list`.

Comment: In `A`, `my_abstract_property` is an instance property. In `B`, it's a class attribute.